# Why does this snippet return "error:areq Bad Argument"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could you explain me why the following code return [Error: error:areq
Bad Argument](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=SimpleController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined)?

(see [live example](http://jsbin.com/xizekudezu/1/watch))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script>
    function SimpleController($scope) {
        $scope.users = [
            {name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix'},
            {name: 'Jane True', city:'Washington'}
        ];
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SimpleController">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }}</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real application you should not define your controller in the global window scope,
in the recent version of angular the $controllerProvider doesn't look up by default in the window scope,
since it's a bad practice and should be used only for **demo** purposes.

However you can enable this feature by calling the `allowGlobals()`:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  // this option might be handy for migrating old apps, but please don't use it
  // in new ones!
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

the alternative and recommended way is to define it in a module.

The official documentation helps you a lot in this 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It explains very well why at 30:00 in [AngularJS Fundamentals In 60-ish Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM) the snippet is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't quite define your controller correctly, try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

    testApp.controller('SimpleCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.users = [
            {name: 'Dave Jones', city: 'Phoenix'},
            {name: 'Jane True', city:'Washington'}
        ];
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SimpleCtrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.name }}</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your code is working well, and uses best practices. But Ahmad's answer explains why my snippet was working with previous versions of AngularJS and is not working anymore.